# Error while using DATE_ADD() in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I tried these both statement, but I got the following error: Number found operator expected Error.

```
$statement->execute($OrderID, $StatusID, DATE_ADD( now(), INTERVAL 12:30 HOUR_MINUTE ));

$statement->execute($OrderID, $StatusID, DATE_ADD( now(), INTERVAL '12:30' HOUR_MINUTE ));
```

Can anyone help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What error are you getting? See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/24909).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which db abstraction layer you're using, but try this:

```
$statement->execute($OrderID, $StatusID, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 750 MINUTE));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

You didn’t pay attention to the manual …?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add *clearly* shows that for an INTERVAL `unit` value of `HOUR_MINUTE`, the expected expression format is a string.